# Refreshing a private List variable on language change MVVM and XAML

Tags: c#, xaml, mvvm, win-universal-app, uwp-xaml

In C#, I added a property that returns a list of tuples for a dropdown selection box. The list contains strings from Resource files. On language change, the value in the list is getting updated. But when invoking the property, the returned value is not refreshed.

Below is the code

```
    private List<Tuple<string, string>> _languageList = new List<Tuple<string, string>>
    {
       new Tuple<string, string>("", AppResources.Automatic),
       new Tuple<string, string>("0407", AppResources.LanguageGerman),
       new Tuple<string, string>("0809", AppResources.LanguageUKEnglish),
       new Tuple<string, string>("0409", AppResources.LanguageUSEnglish),
       new Tuple<string, string>("0c0a", AppResources.LanguageSpanish),
       new Tuple<string, string>("0c0c", AppResources.LanguageFrenchCanadian),
       new Tuple<string, string>("040c", AppResources.LanguageFrench),
       new Tuple<string, string>("0413", AppResources.LanguageDutch)
    };

    public List<Tuple<string, string>> LanguageList
    {
          get
          {
               return _languageList;
          }
    }
```

This is how I invoke the tuple value (a keyvalue pair with lcid and language name)

```
SelectedLanguage = LanguageList.FirstOrDefault(q => q.Item1 == CurrentSettings.SelectedLanguage) ?? LanguageList[0];
```

On language update, the resource strings are taking the translated value. But the property LanguageList returns an obsolete list which was initialized at first when the app starts.

Any suggestions on how can I refresh this list on language change?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You need to notify property has changed?

Comment: Everything looks correct, but your problem is unclear. You say "But the property LanguageList returns an obsolete list which was initialized at first when the app starts", this appears completely as expected and correct.  Why  would you need to change this list?  And, if you *do* need to change it, please [edit] and specify **exactly what changes you need to make**.  I could assume that you wish to remove the selected language (no need to list it as an option), in which case you should be using an ObservableCollection, however that's truly unnecessary, so I'm not going to assume that.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. On picking a language from the list, I would switch the resource files to match the chosen language. It is translating the whole application but this list. The App resource references are reflecting the updated language translations. But the property LanguageList is not returning the translated _languageList value. Rather, it is returning the default value (which is English).

Comment: I think you should post a bit more of your code and pictures and try rephrasing the question. There are too many unknowns here even as to what you know about XAML. Do you know you need to call INotifyPropertyChanged.PropertyChanged when a bound property value changes for the UI to update? Or to use INotifyCollectionChanged(ObservableCollection) if you want changes in a list to be reflected in the bound UI? What is `AppResources`?

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this

```
class Language {
  public string Code { get; set; }
  public string Name { get; set; }
}

void LanguageChangeHandler(sender, args) {

   // never overwrite the property       
   Languages.Clear();

   var languages = args.NewLanguages: // or whatever you do 
   foreach (var language in languages) {
     Languages.Add(language);
   }
};

public ObservableCollection<Language> Languages { get; } 
  = new ObservableCollection<Language>();
```

> Then bind your ListView.ItemsSource to Languages.

Want to get the first? Do it the same:

```
SelectedLanguage = Languages
  .FirstOrDefault(q => q.Item1 == CurrentSettings.SelectedLanguage) ?? LanguageList[0];
```

> Worth just chiming in here. I hate Tuples... so much. Is a class so difficult?

I hope this helps. Best of luck!

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion Jerry. I already have made an short cut that worked for me without changing much in the code level. I'll add my fix below as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

The fix I had for this issue is the below code update.
I added a new function as below

```
public void refreshLanguageList() {
  _languageList = new List<Tuple<string, string>>
    {
       new Tuple<string, string>("", AppResources.Automatic),
       new Tuple<string, string>("0407", AppResources.LanguageGerman),
       new Tuple<string, string>("0809", AppResources.LanguageUKEnglish),
       new Tuple<string, string>("0409", AppResources.LanguageUSEnglish),
       new Tuple<string, string>("0c0a", AppResources.LanguageSpanish),
       new Tuple<string, string>("0c0c", AppResources.LanguageFrenchCanadian),
       new Tuple<string, string>("040c", AppResources.LanguageFrench),
       new Tuple<string, string>("0413", AppResources.LanguageDutch)
    };
}
```

And called the function before my LINQ statement

```
refreshLanguageList();
SelectedLanguage = Languages
  .FirstOrDefault(q => q.Item1 == CurrentSettings.SelectedLanguage) ?? LanguageList[0];
```

Refreshing the _languageList by assigning the same list of tuples again with the same data, updates the list with translated text. Hence the property LanguageList renders the correct value.

That's obviously a dirty fix. But that worked fine with my requirement.